# Fixed Spaces for Group Elements

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, simple-groups, gap, computational-algebra

what is the GAP code for finding the fixed space? A list of row vectors that form a base of the vector space $V$ such that $v M = v$ for all $v$ in $V$ and all matrices $M$ in the list $mats$.

Comment: This is rather confusing. Can you please give more context and fix up the language? It's difficult to parse.

Comment: I guess that you have a matrix group acting on a vector space here, so $v$ are from the vector space and $M$ is a list of group elements. Which particular group and vector space you're interested in?

Comment: the double cover of Conway group Co1(2.CO1) and vector space, 24-dimensional module over filed of rationals

Comment: So you're constructing the group using generators from http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/matrep/2Co1G1-Zr24B0 ? (the first pair of A,B; the 2nd link is not working).

Comment: Yes, I am using the first pair of A,B

Comment: Thanks. So you're looking for a basis of $V$ which is a subset of that 24-dimensional module. What is the list `mats` - is it the whole group?

Answer (score 1):

I.e. the common eigenspace (for Eigenvalue 1) of the generators:

For this, you simply calculate the nullspace bases of the generators:

```
null:=List(GeneratorsOfGroup(g),x->NullspaceMat(x-x^0));
```

(Instead of GeneratorsOfGroup(g) you could use mats)

For getting the intersection it is easiest to go to vector spaces:

```
vs:=List(null,x->VectorSpace(Rationals,x));
ise:=Intersection(vs);
BasisVectors(Basis(ise));
```

(Minor caveat: If any of the vector spaces is trivial, the list of basis vectors is empty. In this case, VectorSpace cannot divine what dimension the vectors live in. To allow this situation, VectorSpace takes an optional third argument, a zero vector. So the safest coding would be:

```
zero:=Zero(g.1[1]);  # Zero vector of type first row of first matrix generator
vs:=List(null,x->VectorSpace(Rationals,x,zero));
```

. A similar issue arises for other algebraic structures, and their constructors thus allow an optional extra argument of the appropriate identity element.)

The intersection is calculated using Zassenhaus' Sum-intersection algorithm, so on a matrix level you also could have called:

```
SumIntersectionMat(null[1],null[2]);
```

(but if you have more than two, you would have processed them in iterative pairs, so the vector spaces are more convenient.)

Comment: Thanks! BTW, for generators from http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/matrep/2Co1G1-Zr24B0 the 1st entry of `null` is an empty list, so the line calculating `vs` leads to a method not found.

Comment: But then there isn't a fixed space.

Comment: Yep. And then `SumIntersectionMat` applied to `null` produces the correct result - its 2nd entry, which is a base for the intersection, is an empty list.